# Binding Source Datagridview Formatting Issue

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource

Ok, I have an issue with my forms and I think I'm missing something simple here but just am not seeing it.

I'm working in VB.NET, VS2012, Entity 6+, SQL database.
I have 2 forms. Main form and Child form. I am not using MDIParent/Child properties. What I am doing is on the main form...i have a panel, and i add a control(new child form to that panel). So when i minimize the Main form, it minimizes the child form. I read some places that the mdiParent/child thing was not a good option because it wasn't supported by microsoft anymore. So this panel with the child form was my next option...which works well, everything loads correctly except one thing. On the initial load of my form, my datagridview needs to be formatted which I have code that formats my grid. On load, it hits this code, formats it but when it is done loading, it looks like it goes back to default formatting(no row highlighting based on cell values and now row header numbering). When i click, say a button or checkbox or something that does formatting to that grid on the form, it formats it perfectly fine(shows row highlighting and row header numbering), hitting the exact same code. What am i missing here? Obviously I am, i just can't see it.

My form load consists of getting a datatable, setting that datatable to a binding source(for the filtering use), then setting that binding source to the datagridview.datasource.

Added note, When i remove the child form from the panel and not tie it to main form, and just create a new free floating form and show it...the exact same code does exactly as expected.

Hope i have provide the needed information to understand my problem! Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for anyone else that comes across this issue...I have an answer for you. Sorry i did not post code up above, I really didn't think it would help but apparently i was wrong. Everything up above is correct but this is what i was doing:

```
Public sub showForm()
dim frm as new Form
frm.TopLevel = False

for each C as Control in ParentForm.Controls
if(TypeOf C Is Panel) Then
     If C.Name = "Specific Panel Name" Then 
        C.Controls.Add(frm)
        exit for
     End IF
End IF
next


frm.Show()

end Sub
```

What was happening was, i created a default form...added it to the control, THEN showed the form and formatted it...but it was still showing the default form INSIDE the panel Control even though i formatted it correctly. What i found out was that....i need to switch the code up for it to work correctly like this

```
Public sub showForm()
dim frm as new Form
frm.TopLevel = False


frm.Show()

for each C as Control in ParentForm.Controls
if(TypeOf C Is Panel) Then
     If C.Name = "Specific Panel Name" Then 
        C.Controls.Add(frm)
        exit for
     End IF
End IF
next

end Sub
```

it now does all the formatting FIRST...then adds it to the panel. Hope you all find this helpful as I lost a days worth of work on this particular situation!